# Do browser vendors have access to LocalStorage/cookies?

Tags: cookies, local-storage

Question is pretty much in the title. We have a customer that is very concerned with privacy, and we're making a solution that will rely on data being stored in LocalStorage, so we just need to verify wether browser vendors (they are specifically concerned about Google) has access to read LocalStorage/cookies and connect the data there to the user in case they are logged in to their (Chrome) browser?

The reason they are concerned is because the solution is targeted towards teens and will have them enter some sensitive information, and we need to cache some of that information throughout the solution in either LocalStorage or cookies.

Comment: local storage should not be used for ANY sensitive information... it does not provide the same level of protection as cookies.  Use it for trivial things like UI preferences...  I wouldn't worry about under 18 information being collected by Google.  Google would definitely follow the COPPA laws.

Comment: It's worth noting that Chrome does actually phone home information on "Unwanted Software" that it scans for.  This is done via the Software Reporter Tool.  I don't know if that info falls under COPPA... might ask on law exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no inherent way to read data (such a LocalStorage or cookies) remotely. Aside from catastrophic security flaws, anything that allows access to data from another device means some software *deliberately made that data available to the viewer*. Generally, either the software (browser) needs to actively upload that data to a server, or the software needs to actively reach out to a server to remotely grant it access to local data, or the software needs to also *be* a server, with a listening port that the remote user (in this case, the browser vendor) can connect to in order to read data or retrieve files.

The first of those does happen with some data. For example, many programs have diagnostic uploads where they'll send their developer a notification, exception details, and often at least partial crash dump if the program crashes. There is some chance that a crash dump could contain sensitive data, but you can usually turn off sending those. The program might also report back to its vendor various information about how the software is used - this is commonly termed "telemetry" and may be described in the UI as "help improve [program name]" or "send usage information to [vendor]". It is usually, but not always, opt-in, and in some cases there's no easy way to turn it off. Such telemetry absolutely should not, ever, contain actual user data (like cookies or site storage) but there's nothing *technically* preventing it from doing so. Legally, the vendor's privacy policy might forbid them from doing that, in which case they could be sued if anybody discovered them doing it anyhow.

The second approach - reaching out to a server for commands - is generally only legitimately done for device management purposes. For example, if your device is enrolled in a mobile device management (MDM) solution like Microsoft Intune, the administrator of the MDM system to which it's enrolled has broad access to the device (on a PC, this usually includes the ability to run arbitrary code; on a mobile device, it's usually less complete but might still include the ability to pull files from an app including a browser). In the MDM case, the client isn't even the app, it's the OS itself (or some highly-privileged app running on the OS). Of course, you probably shouldn't have teens entering highly sensitive information into somebody's work device... The other case where you commonly see this sort of access pattern is malware, which after installing on a device will reach out to a "command and control" server. Obviously, if the device is infected with malware, all security restrictions (including who can see site data from the browser) should be assumed compromised.

The last case - app listens for incoming connections - basically never happens in production software outside of purpose-build remote access systems (which a browser is not). That's the sort of thing you see with SSH or remote desktop services... either of which could, potentially, give the remote user access to files such as browser storage. Such listening for remote control is also used to debug software running on a remote device (used by developers to test apps or even whole operating systems) but that's generally disabled on release builds. In any case, such remote access requires having a routable (not behind network address translation or only on a local network interface) IP address for the device, and no firewall in the way (the OS, the internet gateway, and the ISP are all places where such a firewall might block inbound requests, though it's certainly possible for all three to be missing). In general, you don't need to worry about this on a per-app level.

Overall, no trustworthy software would send user data to its developer/vendor, so it comes down to a few simple questions:

- Do you trust the vendor?
- Do you trust the operating system and its vendor?
- Do you trust any high-privilege remote access or device management software that happens to be on the device, and its vendor(s)?
- Do you trust all privileged users who have access to the device, either locally or via remote access / device management systems?

If all of those are "yes", you're fine. If any of them are "no", then don't enter sensitive personal information on the device! It's as simple as that.

Of course, getting your would-be users to consider *you* trustworthy is an exercise left to the reader. I will say - as somebody who has a few times worked on a system that could have been used to access user data through various forms of the above approaches - some people will only trust you if you seem like a Real Company With A Website And Stuff (which is to say, basically anybody), some won't trust anybody or anything except a short list of well-known companies / open source software / something reviewed and approved by a trusted expert, and some are suspicious by default but can be persuaded (the amount of persuasion, and how much it needs to actually legitimately mean anything, depends on the person and their level of general security knowledge / domain expertise).

Answer (score 1):

Do your customers trust Microsoft (Windows) and Apple (macOS), vendors of desktop operating systems, where the browsers are running? Do your customers trust multiple vendors of Android smartphones (every vendor makes some changes or extensions of Android)? A malicious OS vendor could read any data on the OS level and browser could not prevent it.

If you trust the OS and you trust Google as Chrome Vendor, user can use other browsers. Besides Chrome, there are many browsers based on Chromium and available in Internet for desktops as well as available in App Store (Apple), Play Store (Google), App Gallery (Huawei).

Even if you decide to allow only particular browser, you cannot be sure that the user uses namely this browser. In all browsers based on Chromium and FireFox there are extensions that allow to fake user agent, so that your server believes it is another browser type.

What you should really care about, is ecurity of your application. Make sure it is protected against common attacks. In particular, make sure it is protected against XSS, because XSS vulnerability can allow attackers to read any data from local storage.

Comment: The question was meant to be broad enough to encompass every browser vendor. I'm a developer, so don't really know too much about this, so when the client asked if the browser vendors were able to read data stored in localstorage and/or cookies, I was just unsure what to answer. I tried looking around the web for answers but didn't find any. So I thought I'd try here in case anyone had any experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers obviously need to have access  and browsers are created by browser vendors. So browser vendors could make that they have access if they actually want.

What can prevent this are primarily not technical measures, but that browsers vendors don't want to actually have such access - because this would mean to also properly protect these data against unauthorized access, it might mean loss of reputation and trust and there might be laws against this.

While this is true for most browser vendors because they care about their long-term reputation, some browser vendors might not care about this because their business model does not focus on reputation but on collecting as much data as they can get. No technology prevents this - if the user has installed the browser they are at the merci of the vendors implementation.